# C# Reflection typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals) Ambiguous match on netcoreapp2.2

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core

Trying to get the methodInfo for

```
string.Equals(string a, string b, StringComparison comparer)
```

using the following method:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) } );
```

when running it on .netcoreapp2.2 i get

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
```

Looking at the overloads i cannot find anything matching the same signature.

When running in a project targeting 4.6.1 everything works fine

Question:
**How can I target the above stated method without being ambiguous?**

Update 1:

The actual usage:

```
    public static class StringMethodInfos
    {
        public static readonly MethodInfo EqualsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) } );

        public static readonly MethodInfo ContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
    }
```

```
   var info = StringMethodInfos.EqualsMethod;
```

Comment: I just tried it by creating a new console app for .NET Core 2.2 in Visual Studio 2019, dropped in your code and it works, gives me a method, no ambiguity found. Can you outline steps for reproduction?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Found the issue. The caveat was in the definition of the second property of the static class which probably when reflected, was iterated through and executed, which is very odd. I would not expect that at all.

Comment: If you access one static field with an initializer on a type, they will all be initialized.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Could you please post this as an answer please :)